# Merge two different project (back Laravel and front in vue) in one

Tags: laravel, vue.js, merge, nuxt.js, inertiajs

I would like to merge [this](https://github.com/mostafizurhimself/sabziwala) two different code in one. I explain...

I don't want to use the frontend like that (with Nuxt) and I would like to merge the frontend folder in the backend folder but I don't understand how to make the frontend work in "collaboration" with Inertia.

I mean I don't understand how to "transform" my app.js to make the two work together.

Do I have to completely redo my frontend ? Do I have to completely redo my front end to integrate it with Inertia or is it possible (as I think) to do a refactoring to make the two work together.

Comment: You can have them in the same place, running on different ports. You don't need anything specific here. The build/hosting step will probably be the most annoying part but you should be able to run it as simply as before locally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't want use the frontend like that. I don't want use Next with vue. I would just like to use "simple" vue and its router

Comment: First off, it's Nuxt (Vue) and not Next (React). Then, if you want to migrate back from Nuxt to Vue, you need to strip all the Nuxt specific parts. Should not be a lot of work, just more verbose that's all. You don't need any server side content? Vue is an SPA without any SEO optimization.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, missclick, my bad. And yes, I need the backend part (Which works very well) I would like to remove Nuxt and "import" the whole frontend to make it work with the Laravel and Inertia backend (to keep this part functional) I am a Laravel dev but quite a beginner with vue

Comment: So, you want to bring Vue inside of Laravel (Inertia or whatever)? In that case, you will indeed need to move things around a bit. If you wanted Vue alongside, you could have only used backend endpoints but if you want to benefit from Laravel/Inertia somehow, you need to make a setup inside of it yeah. There is probably a detailed on how to achieve such thing in the backend framework itself.

Comment: You can integrate Inertia really easily on Laravel. After intalling laravel  just need to: 
composer require laravel/jetstream and then 
php artisan jetstream:install inertia.

That's all, you will have Vuejs3 and Inertia working together with your laravel project.

Comment: @Jmielh This is when you start a brand new project tho. Here, the question is more about a migration as far as I understand.

Comment: @kissu yes you're right... In Nuxt, there are several global variable (such $auth, $route etc) which you can access easily. And as I want to delete Nuxt, it is more complex to reintegrate these variables to access them. There is still a lot of modification to do to remove Nuxt and import only the view in the Laravel part. It might be easier to redo the whole front end in Inertia directly (for the SSR too)

Comment: It depends how much things Nuxt specific you used yeah. Can be pretty quick or take a bit more code to rewrite it properly. You can also copy pasta from Nuxt to a brand new Laravel project. No magic solution here overall.